# Type errors in haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, types, integer

I literally started learning haskell in the past few hours following [this tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out). I keep getting `Couldn't match type` error when trying to compile the following code:

```
module Main where
import Control.Monad

main = do
    putStrLn "Enter child age"
    input <- getLine
    -- convert the string to int
    let age = read input :: Int
    unless (age == 0) $ do
        -- let ages = []
        -- print age
        -- add child age to list here?
        ages ++ [age]
        main
```

Here is the error:

```
Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]'                                                                         
Expected type: [()]                                                                                        
  Actual type: IO ()
```

I have been searching for several hours trying to understand the issue but have no clue. Why does `ages ++ [age2]` expects a type `IO Int` ? and how to resolve this issue?

update: `ages` is a list which will contain the age of both child. It will be used in future. Also created the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ages ++ [age1]` and `ages ++ [age2]` are expressions that result in `[Int]`. They don’t modify `ages`; `ages` is just a value. Since you’re not using `ages` at all, a really simple fix would just be to take all three lines out:

```
let ages = []
ages ++ [age1]
ages ++ [age2]
```

`ages` can be built from `age1` and `age2` later if you were going to use it as `[age1, age2]`. If you were wanting to use a list to not repeat yourself, you’d probably do it more along these lines in Haskell:

```
readAge :: String -> IO Int
readAge prompt = do
    putStrLn prompt
    readLn :: IO Int

main = do
    ages <- mapM readAge ["Enter child 1 age", "Enter child 2 age"]
    print ages
```

To do it in a loop, you could start with:

```
readAges :: IO [Int]
readAges = do
    putStrLn "Enter child age"
    age <- readLn :: IO Int

    if age == 0 then
        return []
    else
        fmap (age:) readAges

main :: IO ()
main = do
    ages <- readAges
    print ages
```

where `fmap (age:) readAges` is short for:

```
ages <- readAges
return $ age : ages
```

Comment: I will be using it in future, I am trying to add the age of both child to a list called `ages`

Comment: thanks for updating the answer. I understand your point. but what I was thinking was to implement this so the user can enter as many child as they want. if I do it like that then we limit the number of child. I will update the code with the loop to show what I mean.

Comment: If you know statically that there will only be 2 inputs, you're better off using a pair rather than a list.

Comment: @RainMan: If your question is appropriate for Stack Overflow, you can ask it and point me to it from here if necessary! You’re more likely to get a timely, complete answer that way. =) If not, I suppose you could send me an e-mail – see https://github.com/minitech.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, variables are immutable. You might be looking for something more like this:

```
inputAges :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
inputAges (0:otherAges) = return otherAges
inputAges ages          = _
```

This recursive function keeps track of the ages in its argument. The first line of the definition checks to see if the latest age read is `0`. If so, it gives you back everything but the `0`. A list will match the pattern `(0:otherAges)` if it has at least one element and its head is `0`. If it matches, the tail is bound to `otherAges`. Otherwise, it goes to the next pattern (here, the next line).

I left the recursive case to be filled in, but I can give some more help on that. You need something that reads in an age and calls itself with a list that has the new age prepended. The reading in part will look much the same as it does in the code in your question.